# Best Practice: Potentially huge Winform grid?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, grid

I am writing an application in VB.NET 2008 that manages software deployment and I want to display a "deployment overview" grid.

The grid will be populated with the names of each application (top row) and the name of each workstation (1st column). The remaining cells will be populated according to whether the corresponding software title has been installed correctly, install failed OR not deployed.

What would be the best way to present this information to the end-user? Could the application 'cope' with maybe a thousand check boxes or would it be better to 'owner-draw' a grid in some way?

I may also require the ability to click on any of these cells to view and/or set other properties.

Many thanks for your help.

John

Answer (score 1):

I have used the .NET's GridDataView without any problems using the Virtual Mode while trying to show over 10000 rows but there are good products out there that are also very good in loading tons of data like [Developer express](http://www.devexpress.com/) XtraGrid and [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/controls/gridview/overview.aspx)'s RadGridView.

The only challenge was keep the UAT people happy with all the noise from several thousands of rows.